# Cant change permission to write a file

Tags: themes, read-only

I wanted to modify some files in /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo. As those were read only, I tried to edit its permission. But it is showing that the owner is root and as I am not the owner I cant change the permissions. Is there any way to modify those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open nautilus (I suppose you're using nautilus as the file manager since it's default in Ubuntu) as root. To do it, open a terminal and run

`sudo nautilus /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo`

You will need your admin password. Nautilus will open and you will have root privileges. Be very, very careful since you can damage your system with such powers. Modify the needed files, save and exit nautilus. Do not change their permissions, it may be harmful.